# Check TCP connection through Jenkins Shell

Tags: jenkins, tcp, connection, firewall, connectivity

To make sure there are no firewall issues, I need to check Jenkins connection with several ports on a remote host. I want to use shell commands in a Jenkins job. Jenkins runs on Linux.

Tried by now: telnet, nc, nmap

All three gave me "not found".

Any alternatives?

Comment: This has helped me:
https://jansipke.nl/test-tcp-connection-without-telnet-nc